# i/o timeout when building docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

my docker has began to give me error almost every time I try to rebuild this week.
Sometimes it works, sometimes gives me error.
It always the same message, i/o timeout.
I dont understand, the docker compose yml is correct I assume, since it has been working fine before.
I have tried to remove all containers with docker-compose down.
and then I tried docker-compose up --build, and also docker-compose up -d.

also, the images name seem to be changing from name to name183214ugruoghuiPHt8 when I rebuild.

anyone out there who knows what to do?
Super grateful for all answers

EDIT
when using docker-compose up -d --build it works sometimes

EDIT 2
when using docker-compose up -d --build several times until it works, I can build atleast

Comment: What platform is this? Linux, Windows, Mac?

Comment: My computer is Windows